# How can I rewrite a boolean value in another php page

Tags: php, variables

I want to rewrite permanently a boolean variable value that is in another file and I don't know how can I do it. Here is an example:
I pass navbar value with get method.

```
function navbarsts($navbar) {
    $file = 'file.php';
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = preg_replace('/\$navbar=\"\";/', '$navbar='.$navbar.';', $content);
    file_put_contents($file, $content); 
}
```

I don't know how can I take the navbar value from file.php

Comment: What's not working.  The question is not clear.

Comment: What's the reason for changing contents of the php file like that, instead of just open up the file and change it manually? Give us some background to help us understand what you're actually trying to do and why. I bet that there's a better way.

Comment: Because I have a landingpage with a top navbar and I need to make an administrator page where you can decide if show($navbar=true;) that top navbar or not($navbar=false;).

Comment: That should be a setting you check with an if-statement in your code, instead of actually changing the contents.

Comment: There is any way to change it's value with preg_replace without use an "if" and check all file.php rows? Maybe using some type of regular expresion ?